# rails server command Error - This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in a unusual way

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I have installed **ruby 2.0.0p247** with **rails 4.0.0** and **mysql2 (0.3.15)** in Windows 7
After creating a new project when i try to run the server it terminated saying that

`This 
application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in a unusual way.`

[image]

I also tried the same in Windows 8.1 but still same error exists

Comment: please post `Gemfile`

Comment: here is gem file http://pastebin.com/MnxPj04k